# How do I change the button only in the div where it was clicked

Tags: angular, typescript

I intend to use three buttons (Download, Edit and Upload).

When I click the Download button, I execute a function and I want to change the Download button to the Edit button. When I click the Edit button, I execute a function and I want to change the Edit button to the Upload button. When I click the Upload button, I execute a function and I want to change the Upload button to the Download button.

My problem is that I can't change the button only on the line where it was clicked.

I've tried to pass the index to the function, but it didn't work correctly.

I used javascript to hide / display the buttons depending on the functions that were executed **(example)** `$ (".class").Css ({"display": "none"});` but it's not the best way :(

Can someone help me?

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gvmxcy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
    <div class="d-flex flex-row" style="margin-top:16px">
        <div class="p-2">{{item.id}}</div>
        <div class="p-2">{{item.name}}</div>
        <div class="p-2 bg-primary" style="margin-left:auto">
            <button (click)="download()">Download</button>
            <!-- <button (click)="edit()">Edit</button>
    <button (click)="upload()">Upload</button> -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**.ts**

```
items=[{
  id:1,
  name:"item1",
},
{
  id:2,
  name:"item2",
},
{
  id:3,
  name:"item3",
},]

download(){
  //change button download to button EDIT
}

edit(){
  //change button edit to button Upload
}

upload(){
  //change button upload to button Download
}
```

[image]

When clicking on the download button, I intend to execute the download function () and change the download button to edit, just on the line where it was clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fj5rvr

Basically we add a property that has the current state of the button and change it whenever the user clicks a button.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ViewChild` variable and `Renderer2` to set `innerHTML` for button

```
this.renderer.setProperty(this.downloadButton.nativeElement, "innerHTML",  "Edit");
```

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
    <div class="d-flex flex-row" style="margin-top:16px">
        <div class="p-2">{{item.id}}</div>
        <div class="p-2">{{item.name}}</div>
        <div class="p-2 bg-primary" style="margin-left:auto">
            <button (click)="download()" #downloadButton>Download</button>
            <!-- <button (click)="edit()">Edit</button>
    <button (click)="upload()">Upload</button> -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

TS:

```
 constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}
  @ViewChild("downloadButton") downloadButton: ElementRef;

  download() {
    //change button download to button EDIT
    this.renderer.setProperty(
      this.downloadButton.nativeElement,
      "innerHTML",
      "Edit"
    );
    //this.downloadButton.nativeElement.innerText = 'Edit';
  }
```

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-91rnzc

Comment: This merely changes the label of the button and will always execute `download()`

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me!